# NullPointerException when inflating custom InfoWindowAdapter

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, google-maps-android-api-2, layout-inflater, android-inflate

I am trying to extract a custom `InfoWindowAdapter` into a separate class file. I started with an inner class which works perfect:

```
public class FoobarMapActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

    protected GoogleMap mMap;
    private final GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter mInfoWindowAdapter;

    public FoobarMapActivity() {
        mInfoWindowAdapter = new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {

            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
                View window = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_info_window, null);
                render(marker, window);
                return window;
            }

            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
                return null;
            }

            private void render(Marker marker, View view) {
                ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.badge)).setImageResource(0);
                TextView titleTextView = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title));
                TextView snippetTextView = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.snippet));
                titleTextView.setText(StringHelper.setTextOrEmpty(marker.getTitle()));
                snippetTextView.setText(StringHelper.setTextOrEmpty(marker.getSnippet()));
            }

        };
    }
```

But as soon as I put the *same* code into a separate class I run into a `NullPointerException` when I inflate the layout.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.from(LayoutInflater.java:210)
  at com.example.foobar.activities.CustomInfoWindowAdapter.<init>(CustomInfoWindowAdapter.java:20)
  at com.example.foobar.activities.FoobarMapActivity.<init>(FoobarMapActivity.java:107)
  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1887)
```

Here is the custom class for the `InfoWindowAdapter`:

```
package com.example.foobar.activities;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;

import com.example.foobar.R;
import com.example.foobar.utils.StringHelper;

public class CustomInfoWindowAdapter implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {

    protected View mWindow;

    public CustomInfoWindowAdapter(Context context) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        mWindow = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_info_window, null);
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        render(marker, mWindow);
        return mWindow;


    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
        return null;
    }

    private void render(Marker marker, View view) {
        ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.badge)).setImageResource(0);
        TextView titleTextView = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title));
        TextView snippetTextView = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.snippet));
        titleTextView.setText(StringHelper.setTextOrEmpty(marker.getTitle()));
        snippetTextView.setText(StringHelper.setTextOrEmpty(marker.getSnippet()));
    }

}
```

Here I instatiate the custom adapter:

```
public class FoobarMapActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

    private final GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter mInfoWindowAdapter;

    public FoobarMapActivity() {
        mInfoWindowAdapter = new CustomInfoWindowAdapter(getBaseContext()); // line 107
    }
```

Comment: Provide your xml custom_info_window

Comment: The XML should not be the problem since it works with the inner class.

Comment: @MDMalik Please revert your edit: I included the imports on purpose since this could be the cause of the problem, e.g. the reference to `R.`.

Comment: @JJD What is FoobarMapActivity.java:107 and CustomInfoWindowAdapter.java:20 can u tell me?

Comment: @Pratik I appended the line numbers in the code as comments.

Comment: public class FoobarMapActivity  //  public TreesMapActivity()   WAT?

Comment: @BoD Fixed the name clash.

Answer (score 2):

Please move this line:

```
mInfoWindowAdapter = new CustomInfoWindowAdapter(getBaseContext());
```

into `onCreate` and replace `getBaseContext()` with `this`.

You are doing something against the platform. `onCreate` is your constructor and you should not use Java constructor when working with `Activities`.

Comment: Indeed, please remove your constructor, and use onCreate instead.  Dianne Hackborn (from the Android team) said: "Simple answer: if you are implementing a component like Activity, Service, and ContentProvider, don't implement a constructor.  (That is just use the default empty constructor).  Whatever you think you want to do in the constructor...  you very like don't, and should do in onCreate() instead." - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/70VaBROqcxg

Comment: What would be your suggestion to ensure the instance is constructed once only then?

Comment: @JJD `onCreate` is called only once just after constructor is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have NullReference in render function
Try to add null checking:

```
private void render(Marker marker, View view) {
        if (view == null || marker == null)
          return;
        ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.badge)).setImageResource(0);
        TextView titleTextView = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title));
        TextView snippetTextView = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.snippet));
        if (titleTextView != null)
          titleTextView.setText(StringHelper.setTextOrEmpty(marker.getTitle()));
        if (snippetTextView!= null)
          snippetTextView.setText(StringHelper.setTextOrEmpty(marker.getSnippet()));
    }
```

EDITED:

Try to get LayoutInflater another way:

```
mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

and also check that context is not null.

EDITED2:

Try

```
mInfoWindowAdapter = new CustomInfoWindowAdapter(this);
```

Comment: Please read the stacktrace. The error occurs when the layout is inflated in the constructor of `CustomInfoWindowAdapter`.

Comment: The same exception is thrown when I use `context.getSystemService()` to retrieve the inflater.

Comment: So, we have another question - why context passed in constructor is null :) Can you provide code, where you create and set this adapter for map?

Comment: Pass `this` to the adapter causes an `IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()`. I tried both variation to retrieve the inflater. I cannot move the instantiation info `onCreate` since I declared it to be final.

Comment: Why did you mark adapter as final? Is it possible to make it standart class variable and move adapter constructor into onCreate?

Comment: I declare the adapter as `final` to avoid recreating it every once in a while.

Comment: I think you have more problems with this solution, because your adapter anyway will create info view again on each call.

Comment: I can avoid this by moving `mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_info_window, null);` into the constructor.

Comment: Do you mean to inflate view into activity and pass it into adapter, than adapter will return this view?

Comment: So, you are really avoid recreating, but your problem still not solved?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `getApplicationContext()` or your Activity's context instead of `getBaseContext()`.
`Context context = this;` make context globle to your activity.

Comment: Passing `getApplicationContext()` also causes a `NullPointerException. This is also against [how you should use context](http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/06/context/?utm_source=Android+Weekly&utm_campaign=78ad4cb95e-Android_Weekly_64&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_4eb677ad19-78ad4cb95e-330180005).